# How to load data from S3 into vertica

Tags: amazon-s3, vertica

I have a vertica clusters on AWS with three nodes.
I also have some text files and gzip files in S3.
I want to load those files from S3 into vertica database tables.
What would be steps? Could not find any straightforward guide.
Is there anything like redshift copy command?

Comment: Have you read the [guide](https://community.dev.hp.com/t5/Vertica-Blog/Automatic-HP-Vertica-Database-Loader-for-AWS-S3/ba-p/230344) for loading from S3?

Comment: Why the negative vote!! The doc that Kermit provided is complex one and I asked something similar to copy command of redshift if there is any. If you do not of that kind of command for vertica then dont answer. Why the negative point!

Answer (score 1):

Loading data to Vertica from S3 bucket become very simple. At this point you do not need to have data on node. So there is no need to do anything with s3getfile / s3cmd / s3fs. Starting from version 7.2.2 Vertica shipped with Vertica Library for Amazon Web Services. This library will allow you to use URL to your data file directly in the COPY command. You can use an HTTPS URL or an S3 URL. All you going to need is AWS access keys and URL to your data file.

Your COPY command could be as simple as:

```
COPY test_schema.test_load SOURCE S3(url='https://s3.amazonaws.com/yourbucket/sample_load.csv');
```

Here is the link to a post which covers usage of Vertica Library for Amazon Web Services in great detail: http://www.dbjungle.com/loading-data-from-aws-s3-bucket-to-vertica-made-easy/

Comment: Did you also try by  creating a aws role? It is not working for me..Anyone else tried?

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is @Kermit's comment. It isn't really **that** hard, the guide is pretty good.

I don't really think this is that much easier, but you could also stream it [from S3 using `curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2014-10/0006.html) and pipe this to a vsql session executing `COPY FROM STDIN`.

Something like (where s3getfile is a script calling curl with all the params you need):

```
s3getfile /path/to/file | vsql -h host -U user -w password -c 'COPY mytable FROM STDIN'
```

Answer (score -1):

The document that Kermit pointed to would be ideal to have configured, but it is quite complex to do it.

What you can do instead is create a bucket in S3 and mount that bucket on your linux host.

**Here is a short article on you can do this :**

[HOW TO MOUNT AWS S3 BUCKET INTO AWS EC2 INSTANCE STEP BY STEP](http://www.aodba.com/how-to-mount-aws-s3-bucket-into-aws-ec2-instance-step-by-step/) 
Hope this helps :)